# compiler complaining when returning char pointer array

Tags: c, string, pointers, char

I'm trying to return an array of char pointers but compiler doesn't seem to like it.

```
char*[] get_multiple(int x) {
    char *tmp[x];
    int i;
    for (i=0;i<x;i++)
        tmp[i]=strdup("abc");
    return tmp;
}
```

The compiler errors out with the following:

```
error: expected identifier or '(' before '[' token
```

*on line 1*

Any idea why the compiler doesn't like it and how to fix it?
(I know I can alternatively pass in a structure from the caller to store the return pointers, but I want to avoid doing that)

Comment: I would recommend NOT doing it this way! Please, please don't return the array that way! It is allocated on the stack and its memory will be "freed" as soon as the function returns. Also, the array WON'T be copied to your destination!!! You can't assign an array to an array, it doesn't work like that!!!

Comment: what is actually being returned is a pointer to the block of memory allocated by strdup from the heap.

Comment: Sorry, my comment was quite brief, I've expressed my concerns in an answer to your question. I hope that it explains what I meant above.

Comment: @user967850 incorrect. What is being returned is a local automatic variable the content of which is an array of pointers to allocated memory.

Answer (score 2):

Allow me to add to @Lidong Guo's answer (quoted below)

> You can't create a array by :`char * tmp[x]`,since x is known runtime!
>
> use `char **tmp = malloc(x*sizeof(char  *));` instead

By looking at your code, I can see that you have misunderstood either what the array label `tmp` actually represents or where `tmp` is actually located.

When you allocate a variable (or an array of *static* size) in a function, it is stored on the **stack**, in your current **stack frame**. This *stack frame* is destroyed/freed as soon as the function returns and you **should NOT** be using/referencing that memory any more!!!

`tmp` is a label that represents the memory address at which the `tmp` array is located. This is on the stack so when your function returns it is no longer a valid pointer!

Forgive me if you already know this but judging by your terminology I suspect you might not.

In C you CAN NOT assign arrays to other arrays!

```
int array1[10], array2[10];

// ... Put some values into array 1 ...

array2 = array1; // ILLEGAL! DOES NOT COPY AN ARRAY
```

Similarly, if you return `tmp` you are returning the address, NOT the array so if you are assigning it to another variable you should be copying it instead of *assigning* it!

Hence C does not allow you to *return an array* and you should be returning **pointers** instead.

But even when you return a *pointer* to `tmp` you will be in trouble because of the way you are trying to allocate it (on the stack) so @Lidong Guo suggested that you allocate it on the Heap where it can live even after your function returns. However, this means that you will need to remember to free that memory!

So a rewrite of your function using @Lidong Guo's code would look like

```
char** get_multiple(int x) {
    char **tmp = malloc(x * sizeof(char*));
    int i;
    for (i=0;i<x;i++)
        tmp[i]=strdup("abc");
    return tmp;
}
```

And a hypothetical main would use it like so:

```
int main()
{
    char** multiple7;

    multiple7 = get_multiple(7);

    // Do some stuff on multiple 7
    free(multiple7[3]);

    // Do some more stuff ...

    // Don't forget to free multiple7 array memory too
    free(multiple7);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two types that you can't use as return types of functions:

1. Function types
2. Array types

What you need to do is declare a function that returns a pointer to pointer to char, or `char **`. You must allocate enough memory to store the pointers to the strings — so, if you need 7 strings, you must allocate enough space to hold at least 7 `char *` objects — and then you must allocate space for each of the 7 strings and assign these to the `char *` you just allocated. Alternatively, if all of the strings in this array will have a maximum length, you can declare one contiguous block of memory and calculate the offset to each string.

To aid memory management, it might help to also create a `free_multiple` function.

```
char **get_multiple(size_t max)
{
    char **multiple = malloc(max * sizeof(*multiple));
    for (size_t i = 0; i < max; i++)
        multiple[i] = malloc(/* determine max length of string including null terminator */);
    return multiple;
}

void free_multiple(char **multiple, size_t max)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < max; i++)
        free(multiple[i]); /* free individual strings */
    free(multiple); /* free the container as well */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't create a array by :`char * tmp[x]`,since x is known runtime!

use `char **tmp = malloc(x*sizeof(char  *));` instead

Comment: Variable length arrays have been part of C for nearly 14 years.